# Dagger 2 singleton in multiple instances

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dagger-2

I just tested out Dagger 2 and I am having some strange behaviour regarding the singleton annotation. I created some test code to show my problem.

My Module:

```
@Module
public class App {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ThingA provideThingA(){
        return new ConcreteThingA();
    }

}
```

Interface of the thing I want in singleton:

```
public interface ThingA {
    void showMyId();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class ConcreteThingA implements ThingA {
    @Override
    public void showMyId() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

Code that executes Dagger:

```
public void doStuff() {
    ThingA thingA=DaggerThingAComponent.create().provideThingA();
    ThingA thingB=DaggerThingAComponent.create().provideThingA();
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

And here is a screenshot showing that I do not get the same instance when I ask for it twice. Have I missed something fundamental? ThingA is just a silly name and in my actual application I would like to have this singleton behaviour on my services.

[image: Debug screenshot]

Comment: What does `DaggerThingAComponent.create()` look like? Are you caching the component instance or are you creating a new one on each call?

Comment: @EgorN You nailed it. Dagger enforces singleton behavior within the lifetime of the component, so creating two components is tantamount to creating two applications each with their own singleton.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The trick is that Dagger enforces scope/lifecycle through components, and you've created two separate components here:

```
ThingA thingA = DaggerThingAComponent.create().provideThingA();
ThingA thingB = DaggerThingAComponent.create().provideThingA();
```

Each time you create the new top-level @Singleton-annotated Component, Dagger creates a brand new object graph with a brand new container for each @Singleton object. You should have this instead:

```
ThingAComponent component = DaggerThingAComponent.create();
ThingA thingA = component.provideThingA();
ThingA thingB = component.provideThingA();  // thingA == thingB
```

Of course, anything further accessed through the dependency graph all comes from the same component, so this will preserve the singleton behavior you're looking for.

---

In most cases, you should not need to pass around the Component: The Component should be used for top-level components, and anything accessible through the injector should @Inject its dependencies (which means it shouldn't need a reference to the component itself). This might appear problematic during the migration to DI or Dagger, but creating multiple @Singleton components is not the way around it. Instead, try one of the following:

- If you need multiple instances of something, you can always inject `Provider<T>` instead of `T` whether or not you've created a `@Provides` method. For that matter, you can inject a `Lazy<T>` if you only need zero or one copies of a particular dependency, particularly if the creation of that object is particularly heavy.
- You can @Inject the component itself if you need it deep within the object graph, though it's always preferable to `@Inject Provider<T> tProvider` instead of `@Inject YourComponent` just to call `YourComponent.getT`.
- In some cases, including Android, it may make sense to save the component to a globally-accessible field, either as an instance field in your Application or as a static field somewhere else. This is specifically because Android creates objects on its own, reflectively, rather than getting injected instances from the graph. For all other cases, inject your dependencies to avoid needing to pass around the component.

See also: [Bindings in the graph](http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#bindings-in-the-graph) from the Dagger 2 Users Guide

Comment: But how do I do to retrieve an object handled by Daggar from different places? I would like to avoid passing the component instance all over the app...

Comment: @why_vincent Updated answer to include alternatives. In general, inject the dependencies you need, rather than trying to pass around the Component.